# Finding maximum efficiency of the car engine using derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the function

$$y = 0.76x - 0.00004x^3 $$

The efficiency of a car engine in percentage is denoted by $y$ , where $x$ is the speed of the car in km/h and $x$ is more than or equal to $0$ . What is the maximum efficiency of the car engine ?

I found out that the maximum point is

$(40, 80\frac{24}{25} ) $

I have no clue what the question is asking . Any hints will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

You may have made an error. So $y=0.76x-0.00004x^3$ models the efficiency of the engine in terms of car speed. You should differentiate with respect to $x$ to obtain
$$\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{d}{dx}(0.76x-0.00004x^3)=0.76-0.00012x^2$$
and then you solve $\frac{d}{dx}y=0$ to find the maximum point as $$0=0.76-0.00012x^2\implies x\approx\pm79.58$$
note that we cannot have a negative speed (cannot have a negative magnitude for velocity). This $x$ value for the maximum is different from the one you have. This $x$ value then yields a maximum $y$ value as $y\approx40.32$.

You have the right approach, you would use calculus to find the maximum $y$ value by differentiating with respect to $x$ and then finding the roots. However, you may have made a mistake or some arithmetic error. The maximum $y$ value is then the answer to your question (i.e. $40.32\%$ is roughly the maximum efficiency for the car engine).